# How to access craft custom variable from PHP

Tags: modules, variable, custom

We are using a custom variable initalized like this in our module:

```
    Event::on(CraftVariable::class, CraftVariable::EVENT_INIT,
        function (Event $event) {
            /** @var CraftVariable $variable */
            $variable = $event->sender;
            $variable->set('myvar', MyVar::class);
        }
    );
```

The variable can be access from TWIG via

```
    {{ craft.myvar.WHATEVER }}
```

But how can I access it from PHP, e.g. from an adjuster or another controller?

Answer (score 1):

Because `MyVar` is a service, the easiest solution is to just access it the same way you'd access any other service, e.g.:

```
$whatever = MyModule::getInstance()->myVar->whatever
```

Comment: This does not work. It would require to keep a reference to myVar in MyModule, which works if I'm in control over my module but not for foreign craft.something variables.

Comment: Let's say I want to access craft.blitz from PHP... (Blitz Cache)

Comment: OK, at least for Blitz I found out, that you can simply use Blitz::$plugin-> to access the Blitz object.